# Compare Fasta sequences to substring of multicast file and change ID names

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I am trying to compare two multifasta files. One has microRNA precursors (70nt) the other one has mature microRNAs (22nt). I want to compare the mature microRNAs to the first 20 nt of the precursors file and if the sequence is included I want it to change the IDs in the mature to >ID_5p. So far I wrote a script that gives me an output that is just some sequences from my mature file replicated many times. Could you help me ?

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for mature in SeqIO.parse("mature_microRNAs_final.txt", "fasta"):
    mature.id
    repr(mature.seq)
    len(mature)

    for precursors in SeqIO.parse("precursors_microRNAs_final.txt", "fasta"):
        precursors.id, precursors.seq, len(precursors.seq)
        precursors_5p = precursors.seq[0:20]

        for seq in mature:
            if mature.seq == precursors_5p:
                print(mature.id+"_5p" , "\n" + mature.seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested loop here (which is leading to your repeated output), instead store the relevant precursors sequences and compare to the mature sequences:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

precursors = {
    record.seq[:20] for record in SeqIO.parse("precursors_microRNAs_final.txt", "fasta")
}

for record in SeqIO.parse("mature_microRNAs_final.txt", "fasta"):
    if record.seq[:20] in precursors:
        record.id += "_5p"
        record.description = record.id + " " + record.description.split(" ", 1)[1]
    print(record.format("fasta"))
```

Note here I'm assuming you just want the first 20 nucleotides of the mature records to be identical to any of the first 20 nucleotides of the pre-cursor records. The solution could be adapated for other criteria.

Comment: Thanks !
I actually modified your script a bit and I got exactly what I wanted. I am pasting it here in case it could use someone in the future.

``` from Bio import SeqIO
   precursors = {
    record.seq[:20] for record in SeqIO.parse("precursors_microRNAs_final.txt", "fasta")
}

for record in SeqIO.parse("mature_microRNAs_final.txt", "fasta"):
    if record.seq[:20] in precursors:
        print(">"+record.id+"_5p","\n" + record.seq)
    else:
        print(">"+record.id+"_3p","\n" + record.seq) ```

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios It's better to modify the `id` and `description` like a showed and then use `print(record.format("fasta"))`. This will be more robust to other FASTA header line formats